# Stress testing windows azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, stress-testing

I'm having two Azure Cloud Services, which is running my two ASP.Net applications, and two Windows Azure Virtual Machine running IIS Media Services. I'm using these VMs as a Media Server to deliver Smooth Streaming contents on my Azure Cloud Services, my websites.

Now I want to do the stress testing.

Can you please tell me:

1. How can I test my both Azure Cloud Services?
2. How can I test my both virtual machine with delivering smooth streaming.

I tried [THIS](http://blog.aditi.com/code/a-complete-guide-to-wcat/) but failed to configure WCAT Controller on my VM also I tried with [loadstorm](http://loadstorm.com).

Thanks
Dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I little bit offtopic, but have you consider using [azure media services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/solutions/media/)? it supports on demand and live streaming plus a set of options to use 3d party encoders, encryption, drm protection.

Comment: Thanks George, azure media services doesn't provide live streaming in my case. I'm using azure virtual machines for live streaming. Can you please provide me some azure media services live streaming sources?

Comment: Azure Media Services team is actively working on releasing live streaming soon. I am not entitled to disclose dates, but if you planning to use live streaming i will recommend to contact product PMs through forum [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/) . As for any Azure product there will set of API's to archive scenario goals. Stay tuned. It is coming

Comment: Thanks George, I'm planning for the azure media services live streaming. It's in coming soon section. I read it from[link](http://mingfeiy.com/).